# Longtext data type in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Longtext datatype is the largest capacity(4bytes) datatype in mysql. But it is not enough to store website content page. I’ve tried several times and searched well. And I think MYSQL can able to store maximum of 16KB for Each table.  So I’m not able to store all page contents into our table “PAGE”.  I’m searching for how to recover this.  I’ve worked out with sample text i/p. It works well. But our original contents have more images. Images taking more spaces.

Comment: If you're feeding over 4Gbytes to viewers to your website as your content page.... you'll probably have very few visitors to that page because they'll give up while waiting for it to download.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you taken a look at the [TEXT and BLOB types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)?

The maximum size of a table is on [the order of terabytes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/full-table.html).

Answer (score 7):

A `LONGTEXT` field can contain up to 4 Gb per field - less in older MySQL versions.

These values are stored in a separate location from the rest of the record. Only a 4 byte pointer is stored in the record itself, so only those 4 bytes count for the maximum record size.

Mind you: table size, is record size times number of records.